# Text::LineFold: Setting "ColMax"

Tags: perl, unicode, printing

It looks like setting "ColMax" works, but it issues two warnings. Am I doing something wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
use Term::ReadKey;
use Text::LineFold;
use Term::Choose qw(choose);

my %text = (
    a => 'aaaaaaaaaa ' x 100,
    b => 'bbbbbbbbbb ' x 100,
    c => 'cccccccccc ' x 100,
);

my $line_fold = Text::LineFold->new(
    Charset       => 'utf-8',
    OutputCharset => '_UNICODE_',
    Urgent        => 'FORCE',
);

while ( 1 ) {
    my $choice = choose( [ undef, 'a', 'b', 'c' ], { undef => 'Exit' } );
    last if ! defined $choice;
    $line_fold->config( 'ColMax', GetTerminalSize );
    print $line_fold->fold( '' , '', $text{$choice} );
}
```

---

```
_config: Setting unknown option 35 at [...]/Unicode/LineBreak.pm line 217.
_config: Setting unknown option 0 at [...]/Unicode/LineBreak.pm line 217.
# normal output ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in my script. Now it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
use Term::ReadKey;
use Text::LineFold;
use Term::Choose qw(choose);

my %text = (
    a => 'aaaaaaaaaa ' x 100,
    b => 'bbbbbbbbbb ' x 100,
    c => 'cccccccccc ' x 100,
);

my $line_fold = Text::LineFold->new(
    Charset       => 'utf-8',
    OutputCharset => '_UNICODE_',
    Urgent        => 'FORCE',
);

while ( 1 ) {
    my $choice = choose( [ undef, 'a', 'b', 'c' ], { undef => 'Exit' } );
    last if ! defined $choice;
    $line_fold->config( 'ColMax', ( GetTerminalSize )[0] );
    print $line_fold->fold( '' , '', $text{$choice} );
}
```